# node pagination in json array

Tags: node.js, json, mongodb, pagination

I have implemented the following code for pagination but I am unable to make it work. I need to complete it with the following json data:

following code is for `Vt.js` file

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const cors = require('cors');
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
app.use(cors())
var url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/";

var pagination = require('pagination');
var paginator = pagination.create('search', {
  prelink: '/users',
  current: 2,
  rowsPerPage: 2,
  totalResult: 10020
});
console.log(paginator.render());

app.get('/users', function(req, res) {

  MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
    if (err)
      throw err;
    var dbo = db.db("MyNewDatabase");
    var data = dbo.collection("VirtualCapitalDB").find({}).toArray(function(err, result) {
      if (err)
        throw err;
      console.log(result);
      res.json(result);

      db.close();
    });
  });
})

app.listen(8080, ()=>console.log('Listening on port 8080'));
```

once you access it without pagination you can get following json array

```
[{
  "_id": "5bcb3c77dc56e939187c13a5",
  "firstname": "dumindu",
  "lastname": "nagasinghe",
  "videocount": 5
}, {
  "_id": "5bcb3ce6dc56e939187c13a9",
  "firstname": "cha",
  "lastname": "advv",
  "videocount": 10
}, {
  "_id": "5bcb3d4bdc56e939187c13ab",
  "firstname": "dvvs",
  "lastname": "scvssv",
  "videocount": 4
}, {
  "_id": "5bcb3d7adc56e939187c13ac",
  "firstname": "advav",
  "lastname": "dvdvv",
  "videocount": 5
}, {
  "_id": "5bcb40f7a768f83918480a2b",
  "firstname": "advav",
  "lastname": "dvdvv",
  "videocount": 5
}, {
  "_id": "5bcb4103a768f83918480a2c",
  "firstname": "advav",
  "lastname": "dvdvv",
  "videocount": 5
}, {
  "_id": "5bcb4106a768f83918480a2d",
  "firstname": "advav",
  "lastname": "dvdvv",
  "videocount": 5
}, {
  "_id": "5bcb4125a768f83918480a2e",
  "firstname": "advav",
  "lastname": "dvdvv",
  "videocount": 5
}]
```

But I need to add pagination and get the 2 data objects for single page. How to implement that in code?

Answer (score 4):

Best  way to write pagination of array items

```
paginator(items, page, per_page) {

  var page = page || 1,
  per_page = per_page || 10,
  offset = (page - 1) * per_page,

  paginatedItems = items.slice(offset).slice(0, per_page),
  total_pages = Math.ceil(items.length / per_page);
  return {
  page: page,
  per_page: per_page,
  pre_page: page - 1 ? page - 1 : null,
  next_page: (total_pages > page) ? page + 1 : null,
  total: items.length,
  total_pages: total_pages,
  data: paginatedItems
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this module.

```
// Fetch all running lent loans
module.exports.fetchLends = function (req, res, next) {
    var perPage = 5;
    var page = req.body.page || 1;   // req.body.page pass from client, which page required.
    loans
        .find({
            lenderId: req.user._id,
            _disbursed: true,
            _approved: true,
            _completed: false
        })
        .select(
            "lenderId _disbursed _approved _completed userId disbursed_timestamp status principal lender_interest_amount emi_type completed_timestamp disbursed_timestamp emi.lender_interest_amount emi._disbursed emi._completed emi.principal emi.lender_interest_amount emi.status emi.due_date emi.extension_date_1 emi.extension_date_2 emi.extension_date_3"
        )
        .populate({
            path: "userId",
            select: "name"
        })
        .skip(perPage * page - perPage)
        .limit(perPage)
        .sort({
            disbursed_timestamp: -1
        })
        .exec(function (err, loan) {
console.log(loan)
)}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You want to use the [express-paginate](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-paginate) module, it's better suited for this case. See the documentation on their github page.

The [pagination](https://github.com/vanng822/pagination) module you are using needs to  create a new http request to get the data, it's not what you need for your application.